# Commit a "virtual" file in git and making it

Tags: git, virtual

Is this possible to commit a file that don't exist on filesystem on git ?

Exemple :

git add "hello world" "hello.txt"

I want to add hello world in the file hello.txt but i don't want to write hello.txt on my filesystem.

hello.txt don't exist and i don't want it to exist except on the git system.
(i don't want to write this file on my filesystem).
Is there a way to do this ?

Regards

Bussiere

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: That is probably a very bad idea. Any good reason why you don’t want to create the file on the filesystem?

Comment: I consider this useful in combination with a `git filter-branch --index-filter` invocation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this.

```
# write new object to the object database, record its id
obj_id=$(echo hello world | git hash-object --stdin -w)

# add the new file to the index as 'hello.txt'
git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644 $obj_id hello.txt

# Make a new commit adding the new file
git commit -m "Add new file"
```

Comment: Could you explain me the 100644 please ? And it seems to be this the solution thanks.

Comment: It's the mode parameter for a non-executable regular file. `git help update-index`

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create the file locally, add to git, commit and push to the repository. Then delete the local file and add it to .gitignore so it doesnt get pulled down again.

Although I suspect that may not meet your requirement so may need more context

Comment: I want to add forum post as file in a git (with a trigger), each time a new post is made i want to add it to a git as a file. Thanks